# How to convert Html page to Pdf in android studio

Tags: java, android, html, pdf, converters

I know this question has been asked previously but still, I can't convert the HTML file to pdf. I have tried some solutions provided on the internet but they are outdated. It would be a big help if someone can help me solve my issue. I am saving the HTML file with the following lines of code.

```
 String directory_path = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null));
        File file = new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String targetPdf = directory_path+"myFile.html";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);

        String html = Html.toHtml(text.getText());

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            byte[] data = html.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.close();
            Log.e(TAG, "File Save : " + filePath.getPath());
            Toast.makeText(this,"Saved in "+filePath.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You're never converting anything to PDF in that code.  You're taking HTML, converting it to an Android Spannable (which will only convert a tiny amount of that html), then writing that as text to a file.  Worse you aren't even writing it as text correctly (getBytes is not how you do it).  You need to find a library that can do that, writing it on your own will be months of development work, if not years.

Comment: I am taking input from user in edit text then applying some features like bold and italic on selected text. Then, I am storing that spannable string in html. Now I need to convert that html file to pdf. I tried to find some library to do all of the above functionality but didn't find any. Can you suggest to me any library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(directionPath, "name_file.pdf");
String htmlString = "<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>";
converter.convert(getContext(), htmlString, file);
```

click
[here](https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java) to add file `PdfConverter`

Comment: It gives an error on PdfConverter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).